# Group time period within a time period based on majority of duration

Tags: sql, presto, amazon-athena

I'm using Presto SQL in AWS Athena.

I'll call the start and end time- **time groupings**.  Ok, so I want to assign a 15 minute **time slot** to each time grouping. The 15 minute time slots would be starting with midnight and just be buckets of time in 15 minute increments. So, 00:15, 00:30, 00:45, 01:00, etc. I want to assign the 15 minute time slots based on the MAJORITY of the time grouping falling within the time slot.

Here's what I want to see.

```
duration starttime                 endtime                   timeslot
60       2019-10-07 03:30:40.000   2019-10-07 03:31:40.000   2019-10-07 03:30:00.000
60       2019-10-07 04:00:10.000   2019-10-07 04:01:10.000   2019-10-07 04:00:00.000
60       2019-10-07 04:29:40.000   2019-10-07 04:30:40.000   2019-10-07 04:30:00.000
```

If you take a look at the third line in the table, I want it to fall in the `04:30` time slot because 40 seconds of the the time grouping would be with in that time slot and only 20 seconds is in the `04:15` time slot.

This is what I've come up with but it only assigns a time slot based on where the `starttime` falls.

```
date_trunc('minute', starttime) - interval '1' minute * (minute(starttime) % 15) as timeslot
```

Can someone please help me with the majority logic and code that I'm going for?

Answer (score 1):

Since I was concerned where the majority of the time grouping fell. I needed to determine where the time grouping midpoint was. So, I created a column for the midpoint with this code:

```
date_add('second', (duration/2), breakstart) as midpoint
```

That resulted in this table:

```
duration starttime                 endtime                   timeslot                  midpoint
60       2019-10-07 03:30:40.000   2019-10-07 03:31:40.000   2019-10-07 03:30:00.000   2019-10-07 03:31:10.000
60       2019-10-07 04:00:10.000   2019-10-07 04:01:10.000   2019-10-07 04:00:00.000   2019-10-07 04:00:40.000
60       2019-10-07 04:29:40.000   2019-10-07 04:30:40.000   2019-10-07 04:30:00.000   2019-10-07 04:30:10.000
```

So, I used the same code that I started with, except I used midpoint instead of starttime. This would show me where the middle of the time grouping fell and would assign the time slot appropriately.

```
date_trunc('minute', midpoint) - interval '1' minute * (minute(midpoint) % 15) as timeslot
```

Note: I wasn't able to put the mipoint code WITHIN the date_trunc code. I had to create the midpoint column first and then call it. If someone is able to do this cleaner, please share!